# Incorporating LiveWallpaper in application

Tags: android, wallpaper

I'm sure all must have seen Twitter application for android. How can i show livewallpaper inside application on my dashboard screen, just like twitter is doing.

I need to do the same thing as they have done, where and image will keep floating around when user views home screen of the application.

Any help would do!!!

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter does not show a live wallpaper, it's just an animation inside the application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my original question remains same.
Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Just use the theme Theme.Wallpaper on your activity in the AndroidManifest.